# How do I get past level 8-4 in The Last Rocket?

Tags: the-last-rocket

I have stared and stared and stared at level 8-4 of [The Last Rocket](http://shauninman.com/lastrocket/) and can't for the life of me figure out how to get to the exit.

[image: The Last Rocket, Level 8-4]

I've flown from each corner of the left and right wall. I've tried walking and flying through what looks like an opening to the right of the bottom fan.  I've tried turning around close to the enemy, to see if I can pull him from the wall.  All to no avail.

**What do I do to get past this level?  How do I get to the exit?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent an e-mail to the [game's creator](http://shauninman.com/), and he responded with the following hint:

> Have you tried exploring the ceiling area to the right of the bottom fan while vertical?

Here's my solution:

> There *is* a grate to the right of the bottom fan, you just have to be as close to the right wall as possible.  If you're having a hard time flying through the grate, keep walking right.